# Loopless NFA equivalent in strength to NFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

For every nondeterministic finite state automata (NFA) that has self-loop(s), there exists an equivalent NFA that does not have any self-loop.

How do I prove this?

Answer (score 8):

Make two copies of your original NFA and connect them in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 5):

create a new state for each self looping state and connect all self looping edges to that state and reconnect that state back to its original state(s) with Epslon\lambda transition [image: this image shows NFA with loops.] while you can transform your self loops to another state like i did as follows [image: NFA that accepts the same language as above stated NFA but without loops.] Images of NFA are created in JFLAP software.

Answer (score 2):

Make a list of self-looping nodes. From left to right of the list, for each node contained, split it into $2$ distinct nodes, connect them (in both directions) by arcs with the same label as the self-loop (that is now deleted), connect each of the two new nodes to other nodes so as each look exactly like the deleted node before (that means all incoming and outgoing arcs are copied exactly).

Do not forget to set the starting node and final nodes appropriately.